# anchorpoint issues with CCUIViewWrapper

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, anchor

I am having some issues understanding and using anchorPoint.  As I understand it, the default anchor is (.5,.5) which applies transforms about the center of objects.  However, when I placed a UIButton into a CCUIViewWrapper, I noticed that scaling it would scale about the *right* side of the object (i.e. if I scaled from 0 to 1, it would grow from right to left).

I wasn't sure what to make of this, but with tinkering found that I had to adjust the anchor point to (0,0) in order to make scaling occur about the center of the object.  Why would this happen?

Further more, while I expect that to make the anchor be the *bottom* left of the object because Cocos2d is bottom left oriented for (0,0), it did not and in fact aligned the *top* left with my wrapper's position value.

In the end, what worked to scale about the center was to make the anchor point (0,0) and position the wrapper using the top left of the object, almost as if it were using the UIView coordinates to place the object.  I'm not certain if this behavior is something occurring strictly with wrapped UIViews in CCUIViewWrappers nor do I know if this is simply correct behavior and I'm completely misunderstanding it.

Can someone clarify and explain?

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem with the wrapper. One of the issue here is that the wrapper attaches the view to the root window instead of the director's OpenGL view, which means it wont respect whatever autorotation the OpenGL view is using. The code looks like it is trying compensate for the difference between UIView and Cocos2d coordinates but doesn't seem to do it properly when it comes to anchor points. I ended up just using UIView coordinates in the end but I did experiment with an alternate method for setting the anchor point by using:

```
uiItem.center = ccp((self.anchorPoint.x - 0.5f) * self.contentSize.width, (self.anchorPoint.y - 0.5f) * self.contentSize.height);
```

At the start of the updateUIViewTransform method in CCUIViewWrappers before setting the view's transform. This makes anchor points behave as expected, at least for views attached directly to a layer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
uiItem.center = ccp((self.anchorPoint.x - 0.5f) * self.contentSize.width, (self.anchorPoint.y - 0.5f) * self.contentSize.height);
```

which set the anchor point to the bottom right, I used:

```
uiItem.center = ccp(-uiItem.bounds.size.height/2, uiItem.bounds.size.width/2);
```

which set it to the center.

The reason the x and y are flipped, I'm guessing it's because my item is rotated by 90.