# CCUIViewWrapper ignores position for UITextView

Tags: ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having trouble positioning a UITextView when using the CCUIViewWrapper.
Whatever I set the position to it always ends up in top left corner of the screen.

I've both tried to set the position in initializer of the UITextView (initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 500, 200, 200) and by changing the position of the wrapper itself.

The size set to the wrapper seems to be honored at all times (i.e what I initialize the UITextView size to is ignored).

Any help in the right direction would be great!

my code looks like this:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 500, 200, 200)];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.text = text;
[textView setEditable:NO];

CCUIViewWrapper* wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:textView];
wrapper setPosition: CGPointMake(200, 200)];
wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
[self addChild:wrapper];
```

This results in a textview with a size of 50x50 and positioned in the top left corner...

CCUIViewWrapper on GitHub:
https://github.com/splhack/CCUIViewWrapper

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.text = text;
[textView setEditable:NO];

CCUIViewWrapper* wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:textView];
wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
wrapper.position = ccp(200,200);
[self addChild:wrapper];
```

Comment: also check out [This Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3857925/anchorpoint-issues-with-ccuiviewwrapper/8003011#8003011). It's about changing the anchor point  and might help fix some positioning problems.